# reading HttpwebResponse json response, C#

Tags: c#, json, rest, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

In one of my apps, I am getting the response from a webrequest. The service is Restful service and will return a result similar to the JSON format below:

```
{
    "id" : "1lad07",
    "text" : "test",
    "url" : "http:\/\/twitpic.com\/1lacuz",
    "width" : 220,
    "height" : 84,
    "size" : 8722,
    "type" : "png",
    "timestamp" : "Wed, 05 May 2010 16:11:48 +0000",
    "user" : {
        "id" : 12345,
        "screen_name" : "twitpicuser"
    }
}
```

and here is my current code:

```
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding(contentEncoding).GetBytes(contents.ToString());
    request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

    using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream()) {

        requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

        using (var twitpicResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()) {

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(twitpicResponse.GetResponseStream())) {

                //What should I do here?

            }

        }

    }
```

How can I read the response? I want the url and the username.

Comment: It might be a good idea to check out Restsharp to do your rest service calls https://github.com/johnsheehan/RestSharp/wiki/Getting-Started will make your life 100000x easier down the track, and you can setup object models for it to decode to.

Comment: @anthonyvscode the wiki/get-started moved to here https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Getting-Started

Answer (score 59, accepted):

First you need an object

```
public class MyObject {
  public string Id {get;set;}
  public string Text {get;set;}
  ...
}
```

Then in here

```
    using (var twitpicResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()) {

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(twitpicResponse.GetResponseStream())) {
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var objText = reader.ReadToEnd();
            MyObject myojb = (MyObject)js.Deserialize(objText,typeof(MyObject));
        }

    }
```

I haven't tested with the hierarchical object you have, but this should give you access to the properties you want.

JavaScriptSerializer System.Web.Script.Serialization

Comment: thanks for the reply. honestly, I was a bit lazy for this question. couple of months ago, I have created a wrapper for Google URL Shortener API and I used System.Web.Extensions library for that too.

Comment: i have tried your code but gives error "No overload method 'Deserialize' take '2' arguments" do i miss something?

Comment: This code is over 3 years old.  There are probably better ways to do this now.  I also don't know what version of the JavaScriptSerializer that was.  It may have changed?

Comment: Hey I revive the thread... if we have an array of array of string.. what is the object structure for that?

Comment: I would recommend using [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/jsonnetvsdotnetserializers.htm) to serialize the Json to an object over `JavaScriptSerializer`. It's more efficent and is now recommended by microsoft for this kind of work over it's own seriaializer.

Comment: var myobj = js.Deserialize<MyObject>(objText);

Answer (score 13):

I'd use RestSharp - https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp

Create class to deserialize to:

```
public class MyObject {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

And the code to get that object:

```
RestClient client = new RestClient("http://whatever.com");
RestRequest request = new RestRequest("path/to/object");
request.AddParameter("id", "123");

// The above code will make a request URL of 
// "http://whatever.com/path/to/object?id=123"
// You can pick and choose what you need

var response = client.Execute<MyObject>(request);

MyObject obj = response.Data;
```

Check out http://restsharp.org/ to get started.

Comment: My response getting source in Content not data

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting source in Content 
Use the following method

```
try
{
    var response = restClient.Execute<List<EmpModel>>(restRequest);

    var jsonContent = response.Content;

    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<EmpModel>>(jsonContent);

    foreach (EmpModel item in data)
    {
        listPassingData?.Add(item);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Data get mathod problem {ex} ");
}
```