# How to get Json information from web

Tags: c#, json

How can I translate the information from the web source to Json? Registered as json on the web..

According to the values I want to show in the table information

I apologize for the language I use translation

MyCode :

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("link");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";   


        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadLine();

            Airport kny = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Airport>(result);

            string fskodu = kny.fsCode; // fs kodu null whyy???

        }

    public class Airport
          {
              [JsonProperty("requestedCode")]
              public string requestedCode { get; set; }



              [JsonProperty("fsCode")]
              public string fsCode { get; set; }
          }
```

Comment: Your code assumes the first line from the stream is valid JSON... Is it? Are there multiple lines in the data? Please show an example of your data

Comment: Thanks Gone..Yes more than one data..{
 "request": {
  "airport": {
   "requestedCode": "KYA",
   "fsCode": "KYA"
  },
  "date": {
   "year": "2016",
   "month": "12",
   "day": "20",
   "interpreted": "2016-12-20"
  },
  "hourOfDay": {
   "requested": "8",
   "interpreted": 8
  },
  "numHours": {
   "requested": "1",
   "interpreted": 1
  },
  "utc": {
   "requested": "false",
   "interpreted": false
  },

Comment: I understand now... will add an answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [reading HttpwebResponse json response, C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493949/reading-httpwebresponse-json-response-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your class to look like this:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public Request request { get; set; }
}

public class Request
{
    public Airport airport { get; set; }
}

public class Airport
{
    public string requestedCode { get; set; }
    public string fsCode { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize with:

```
var kny = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result);
```

Access values like this:

```
kny.request.airport.fsCode; // This is == "KYA"
```

I'm missing out a whole bunch of other properties for brevity, the full class would be a little more complex.

JSON has to be deserialized in its entirety as it represents a complete object, you can't cherry pick one line at a time to get individual properties.

Comment: An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Input string '3.0' is not a valid integer. Path 'appendix.airports[0].utcOffsetHours', line 1, position 1109.

Comment: Change the property 'utcoffsethours' in your airport class to a double instead of integer.